# textbox will show if check box is checked...how to do this validation in model side or view or in javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery, razor

model

```
public class FMMODTrialInputs : UserInputs
{
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

view

```
<tr>
        <th class="SrcFld">
        </th>
        <td class="td1Fld">
            @Html.CheckBox("overrideEffeciveDate", new { id = "overrideEffDate" })
             &nbsp;
            Override Effective Date? 
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <th class="SrcFld">
           <label for="EffectiveDate" id = "lblEffDate">Effective Date</label>:&nbsp;
        </th>
        <td class="td1Fld">
            @Html.TextBox("EffectiveDate", Model.EffectiveDate)
        </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>@Html.Hidden("ClientLoanID", Model.ClientLoanID)</td> 
        <td><input type="submit" id="btnDecision" value="Decision" /> </td>
    </tr>
```

i wanted to display textbox(effective date) if i click the overrideeffdate....please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

in jquery, you can simply add

```
$("#overrideEffDate").change(
    function()
    {
        $("#EffectiveDate").parent().parent().toggle();
    });
```

This will grab the row of the table and toggle visibility.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using editor for, to bind the field ids directly to properties.  Check out the tutorial here:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Add another property to your model representing that checkbox, and add a RequiredIfValidator to your EffectiveDate field, saying its required if OverrideEffectiveDate is set to true:

Model:

```
public class FMMODTrialInputs : UserInputs
{
  public bool? OverrideEffectiveDate { get; set;}

  [RequiredIf("OverrideEffectiveDate", true, ErrorMessage="Required")]
  public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<tr>
    <th class="SrcFld">
    </th>
    <td class="td1Fld">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OverrideEffectiveDate)
         &nbsp;
        Override Effective Date? 
    </td>
    <th class="SrcFld">
       <label for="EffectiveDate" id = "lblEffDate">Effective Date</label>:&nbsp;
    </th>
    <td class="td1Fld">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
    </td>
    </tr>
```

This requires you to have a RequiredIfValidator.  Check out this tutorial on how to have one:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx